# how to use websocket and webrtc?and how to setup server for websocket communication

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, webrtc, backend

I have been practicing web development from 5 months now and i have learned html,css,js,php, mysql but now i want to learn real time communication and i have been learning the theory behind webrtc(signalling,p2p etc) and websockets(open communication) but cannot implement it because of http and ws difference. I might be misunderstood somewhere but ws and http dont work together. How to setup apache or nodejs to use ws and respond to the client? Please help and brief explanation would help a lot to understand rest of the missing concepts.Please take me as a beginner and explain

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: I have tried quora but honestly no one replied. I just need the process to set up a server to use ws.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) might help you get an idea how webRTC works .

simple example

```
var peerConnCfg =  {'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]},
    peerConn= new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnCfg),
    signalingChannel = new WebSocket('ws://my-websocket-server:port/');

peerConn.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
  // send any ice candidates to the other peer, i.e., evt.candidate
  signalingChannel.send(JSON.stringify({ "candidate": evt.candidate }));
};

signalingChannel.onmessage = function (evt) {
  var signal = JSON.parse(evt.data);
  if (signal.sdp)
    peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp));
  else if (signal.candidate)
    peerConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate));
};
```

[basic tutorial can be found here](http://web-engineering.info/node/57)

Comment: thank you. another doubt is how many ways are there to use signalling for p2p connnection.